# Configure domain-wide WebLogic error page

Tags: apache, http, weblogic

In WebLogic, there's a way to customize standard error pages like HTTP 404 inside the web applications using `web.xml`

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee">
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>errors/404.htm</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Is there a way to configure default domain-wide error page for all the applications WebLogic has running without editing `web.xml`? Would it be possible to capture the 404 in Apache and serve a common error page?

Comment: Not yet. We keep managing 404 pages in each application separately :(.

Comment: Any chance you found an answer now?

Comment: @BarbiePylon I can't speak for newer ones, but not for versions up to 11g

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to set the 404 page domain-wide (I doubt there is a way since this is intended to be provided separately by each app).

However, you can catch it from the web-tier. For Apache, you can use the `ErrorDocument` directive. For example, `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html`

Comment: Apache only shows the 404 page for documents which responds itself, not for the pages served by WebLogic Apache plugin :(.

Comment: Interesting....I thought Apache was able to catch any 404 errors propagated from WebLogic through the proxy plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to define an error page in Apache WebLogic plugin:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/plugins/apache.html

Comment: The configured page is displayed when Apache is unable to forward requests to WebLogic, not when WebLogic returns a 404 response. [See doc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/plugins/plugin_params.html#wp1155425)